# Comparing QKeyPress events

Tags: c++, qt

I have two QKey press events I would like to compare, one keypress is entered by my "AddShortcut" form, and I want the main form to compare user keypresses with the keypress entered on my Addshortcut form.

Is there a way of comparing both event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but I will point out the existence of `QAction` in case you haven't seen it yet.  It's the mechanism by which Qt implements keyboard shortcuts and the like:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#details

As for your specific question, the baseline QEvent class does not have equality or comparison operators defined.  Equality would be a fuzzy topic  in any case *(are mouse clicks equal if they are at the same pixel coordinate?  What if Ctrl/Alt/Shift are pressed)*?

If you just want to test two keypress events to see if they're equal, you can first test to see what the event type is on each using [QEvent::type()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qevent.html#type).  If they are both `QEvent::KeyPress` then you can `static_cast<QKeyEvent>` for both events.  Then you can check to see whatever parts you are interested in are equal.

Obviously there is [QKeyEvent::key()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html#key) but there are also modifiers, the text produced, etc:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html

Comment: I converted both KeyEvents to their respected string value, then compared. simple enough.